# CocoaLumberjack 1.9.x legacy macros enabled + DDLogWarn macros redefined

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoalumberjack

I have a project using Cocoalumberjack 2.x as Cocoapod. The project uses Obj-C mostly, but also a few Swift classes.

I allways get these warnings:

```
Disable legacy macros by importing CocoaLumberjack.h or DDLogMacros.h instead of DDLog.h or add `#define DD_LEGACY_MACROS 0` before importing DDLog.h.
```

In the main project I don't have a file that imports DDLog.h. Only CocoaLumberjack in the Pods import DDLog.h.

I also get the `DDLogError macro redefined`, `DDLogInfo macro redefined` etc warning.
What's the problem leading to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the issue stems from the DDLegacyMacros.h missing:

```
#if DD_LEGACY_MACROS
```

on line 21 and:

```
#endif
```

on line 75. Then in DDLog.h, replace:

```
#if DD_LEGACY_MACROS
    #import "DDLegacyMacros.h"
#endif
```

with:

```
#import "DDLegacyMacros.h"
```

https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/commit/9b31277c90d7c3968038af09a7bddd003aa28da9

When applying the new `use_frameworks!` option in Cocoapods, a bridging header
is automatically generated. This bridging header must import `DDLegacyMacros.h`
directly.
This leads to `CocoaLumberjack 1.9.x legacy macros enabled.` and `macro
redefined` warnings.

Therefore it is not enough to merely check the flag in DDLog.h.